# React-router - How to pass data between pages in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a project where I have to pass data from one page to another.
For example, I have `data` on the first page.

```
let data = [
  {id:1, name:'Ford', color:'Red'},
  {id:2, name:'Hyundai', color:'Blue'}
]
```

Here is the first component page where I render this list of data with the name.

```
class ListDetail extends Component {
    constructor();
    handleClick(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <ul>
          {data.map((data,i) => {
            return <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,data)}>{data.name}</li>
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to pass this data to the next page where I need this data and more data than this. I am using React Router 4. Any suggestion or help would be helpful.

Comment: @Andrew there are many many ways to do this. Are you using any kind of state management system like Redux? If so, this data should be stored in your Redux store, where it will be available to all routes. If not, I'd recommend doing so -- it will take a little time to learn but will make your life much easier once you lear the ropes...

Comment: Andrew, alternative to my answer, you can also use the [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for passing data between components when they are deeper down the tree. It's an option, but if you are working with large amounts of data. I'd suggest having a look at Redux as Duhaime suggested. It's a bit of a learning curve, but the free course on [Redux on egghead.io](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) will get you ready for it. The course is made by Dan, the creator of redux.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use the Link component from react-router and specify `to={}` as an object where you specify pathname as the route to go to. Then add a variable e.g. `data` to hold the value you want to pass on. See the example below.

Using the `<Link />` component:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/page",
    state: data // your data array of objects
  }}
>
```

Using `history.push()`

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/page',
    state: data // your data array of objects
})
```

Using either of the above options you can now access `data` on the location object as per the below in your page component.

```
render() {
  const { state } = this.props.location
  return (
    // render logic here
  )
}
```

You can see an example of how to pass a value along with a route in another example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rywo1xx6xn).

Comment: Also need to make sure that the route passes the props during routing. <Route exact path="/path" component={(props) => <View {...props}/>} />

Comment: You suggested Redux, but from what I understand Redux don't hold values when switching URLS is that correct?

Comment: Hey @YuvalLevy, in the context of a single page react app and using react router to manage routing in the frontend, redux manages the state separate from the routes. So, regardless of the route, the state in redux is available to you. Of course if you browse to another site outside of your own app, then that's something else.

Comment: You'll also want to encodeURIComponent the parameters you pass and decodeURIComponent in the receiver for the props.match.params.<variablename> otherwise, if there are forward slashes in the parameter you want passed, React won't call the constructor with props and won't declare any error or console output leaving you guessing.

Comment: How to access data in page component?

Comment: this method won't work in react-router-dom version 6, I will refer this answer if somebody is in search of React-Router-Dom v6 because in v6 we don't have props for location we can use hooks instead while passing state to other components : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68967670/7312335

Answer (score 39):

**Best way to pass data to the target Component**, just copy paste the code and see the magic, I also explained it in depth.

---

**Remember:** in react-router-dom v6 you can use hooks instead.

**version 5.X**

Let's suppose we have two Components first and second. The first has the link which will target the second component.

The first **Component** where the link is, by clicking the link you will go to the target path as in my case it is:`"/details"`.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function firstComponent() {
return(
<>
    <Link to={{
      pathname: '/details',
      state: {id: 1, name: 'sabaoon', shirt: 'green'}
    }} >Learn More</Link>
</>
)
}
```

---

Now in the second **Component** you can access the passed object as:

```
import React from 'react'


export default class Detials extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            value:this.props.location.state,
        }

    }


alertMessage(){
       console.log(this.props.location.state.id);
    }

render(){
return (

    <>
     {/* the below is the id we are accessing */}

      hay! I am detail no {this.props.location.state.id} and my name is 
      {this.props.location.state.name}

      <br/>
      <br/>

 {/* press me to see the log in your browser console */}
<button onClick={()=>{this.alertMessage()}}>click me to see log</button>

    </>

    )
}

}
```

**note**:In version 6 of react-router-dom the above method won't work on class components though you can use functional components of react by using useLocation hook and then you can draw the state object through that location in another component.

---

**version 6**

**How to achieve the same using hooks v6 of react-router-dom**

Let's suppose we have two functional components, first component A, second component B. The component A wants to share data to component B.

**usage of hooks:** (useLocation,useNavigate)

```
import {Link, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

function ComponentA(props) {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const toComponentB=()=>{
navigate('/componentB',{state:{id:1,name:'sabaoon'}});
  }

  return (
   <>
<div> <a onClick={()=>{toComponentB()}}>Component B<a/></div>
</>
  );


}


export default ComponentA;
```

---

**Now we will get the data in Component B.**

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

 function ComponentB() {

    const location = useLocation();
   
        return (

            <>
               
<div>{location.state.name}</div>

            </>
        )
    }

export default ComponentB;
```

Comment: Attempted import error: 'useNavigate' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: are you using v6 or late ?

Comment: yes i am using v6

Comment: Please, try to remove the package through npm and re-install it, check your import statement twice.

Answer (score 17):

You can use react-router's `Link` component and do the following:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/yourPage',
  state: [{id: 1, name: 'Ford', color: 'red'}]
}}> Your Page </Link>
```

and then access the data with `this.props.location.state`

You could also consider using redux for state management in your whole application (https://redux.js.org/).

Comment: Can we pass function ?

Comment: the problem you will face here is that you are passing array of object, so it means you can't access it in the target component via this.props.location.state.id or something, you have to access the array object as this.props.location.state[0].id or this.props.location.state[0].name etc.

Comment: OR You can use map function if you have many objects in the array.

Comment: this method won't work in react-router-dom version 6,  because in v6 we don't have props for location we can use hooks instead while passing state to other components for more details : stackoverflow.com/a/68967670/7312335

Comment: @AmitJS94 you can pass functions by importing the component and then you can pass reference of a function as a prop to the other component, I don't think state will call your function from other component but props would do it. I will leave a small snippet for your understanding: <yourComponent yourFunction={this.yourFunction}/>

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you saved my day

Answer (score 5):

I'm using **react-router-dom** **6.4.3**

The following, which seems to work for other/earlier versions, does not work with **6.4.3**:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Link 
  to={{
  pathname: '/details',
  state: stateObj
  }}>Learn More</Link>
```

A minor change has been made and the below works instead:

```
 <Link 
   to={'/details'}  
   state={stateObj}>Learn More</Link>
```

Notice how the state object is now outside of the ***to*** object?

In the Details page, you can receive the object as follows:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const DetailsPage: FC<{}> = (props) => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  //do stuff with state obj
}
```

Answer (score 3):

how to pass data into another compoent router in reactjs

Login.jsx

```
 handleClickSignIn(){
            console.log("come handle click fun");
            this.props.history.push( {pathname: "/welcome",
            state: { employee:"Steven" }});
      
        }
```

welcome.jsx

```
componentDidMount()
{
  console.log(this.props.location.state.employee);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple to pass data through navigate.( to another component)

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const navigate=useNavigate()
```

"""suppose you need to pass an "value.id" with navigate ,please try this"""

```
onClick={() => {history( /userUpdate,{ state: { id: value.id } })}}
```

"""then in "userUpdate" component =>"""

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'

const { state } = useLocation(); const { id } = state;

console.log(id)
```

"""here is the value.id"""

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your other page is a component you could pass the data as a prop which will be available on the next page. Something to note though, you must use `<Link />` component which available in `react-router 4` as opposed to using `<a></a>` which causes a full page reload hence making access of the data lost.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to send one page in one object same code below you must import your page in your object file and again import your page in your destination file same this:

```
import Home from './componenets/home/home';
import ColdDrink from './componenets/coldDrink/coldDrink';
import HotDrink from './componenets/hotDrink/hotDrink';
import CheaseCake from './componenets/cheaseCake/cheaseCake';
import Lost from './componenets/404/lost';

const link = [
{
name   : "Cold Drink",
link   : "/ColdDrink",
router : <ColdDrink/>
},
{
name   : "Hot Drink",
link   : "/HotDrink",
router : <HotDrink/>
},
{
name   : "chease Cake",
link   : "/CheaseCake",
router : <CheaseCake/>
},
{
name   : "Home",
link   : "/",
router : <Home/>
},
{
name   : "",
link   : "",
router : <Lost/>
}
];
```

and in your destination file you must map your object...

```
const links = (this.props.link);
{links.map((item, i) => (
  {item.router}
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

State data, current data is on the `Checkout.tsx` page, and pass state data on the `App.tsx` page (using typescript)

###### Checkout.tsx page

```js
 import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
 export default function CheckoutPage() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const data = [
    {
      name: "Ngoc",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Kevin",
      id: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Jack",
      id: 3
    },
  ];

   history.push({
    pathname: `/app`, /* this path field is based on your project */
    state: data ? data : [] /* pass state data to app page */,
  });
}
```

###### App.tsx page

```
 import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
 export default function AppPage() {
    const history = useHistory();
    // use useLocation read data form Checkout page
    const location = useLocation<any>();
    const currentDataFromCheckoutPage = location.state;
    // data pass show here
    console.log('currentDataFromCheckoutPage', currentDataFromCheckoutPage);
}
```