# How to access passed data using router from one component to another ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, onclick, react-router-dom

[image: This is the error while accessing passed data variable from previous page using react-router]

```
//import routes from "./routes";
import { Link, withRouter, NavLink, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  console.log(this.props.data.data);
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);
...}
```

### This part of code in slider.js accessing data variable passed from last page, mentioned below

```
        axios
        .post(
          "/get_spec_other",
          {
            selected_country: this.props.selectedCountry,
            selected_disease: this.props.selectedDisease,
            selected_drug: this.props.selectedDrugs,
          },
          { headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          const SpecificationName = Array.from(res.data);
          console.log(res.data);
          this.props.history.push({pathname: '/slider', data: res.data});

          alert(res.data);
```

### This is where I am passing data to /slider, and opening slider.js .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a functional component and expecting "this" to be there.
This is how it should look: (Notice the props declared in the function argument of App)

```
//import routes from "./routes";
import { Link, withRouter, NavLink, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App(props) {
  console.log(props.data.data);
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);
...}
```

Another thing you will need to do is review that you are using the proper hooks to obtain the data:
https://css-tricks.com/the-hooks-of-react-router/

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

`App
src/App.js:26
  23 | import { Link, withRouter, NavLink, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";`

  24 | 

  `25 | export default function App(props) {`

`> 26 |   console.log(props.data.data);`
  `27 |   const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
  28 |   const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);
  29 |   const [value3, setValue3] = useState(0);`

Comment: As If I use only, console.log(props.data), it gives undefined

Comment: You need to analyze where the props are coming from. console.log(props) and see what is provided. Perhaps the router is passing the data in a different way to your component.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but it is empty

Comment: You may want to read:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238637/react-router-how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-react

Comment: Thankyou!
I realized where I was going wrong, I was not passing data from parent to child component

`render() {
    const { data } = this.props.location
    console.log(data);
...}`

.................

`return (
....
 <App data={data}/>
...}`

...........

`export default function App(data) {
  //const { data } = props.location
  console.log(data);
......}
`

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou! I realized where I was going wrong, I was not passing data from parent to child component

```
render() {     
const { data } = this.props.location     
console.log(data); ...
}
```

---

```
return ( 
....  
<App data={data}/> 
...
}
```

---

```
export default function App(data) {   
//const { data } = props.location   
console.log(data); 
......
}
```